# Nurbs path doesn't go fully closed

Tags: bezier-curves

When I create a NURBs path and try to add depth and resolution to it it creates half a cylinder rather than a full one... Any idea what's causing that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the *Fill Mode* from the *Properties Window > Object Data > Shape > Fill Mode*.

This will vary depending on whether your curve is set to *2D* or *3D*. Either set it to *Full* for *3D*, or *None* for *2D*.

[image]

Comment: oh yeah, you're right. god that's so simple >.>